# Delete characters after the second space using jquery?

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a list of documents that start like this...

```
MR 100 12.12.10
MR 100 11.12.10
MR 201 03.06.08
MR 458 04.06.09
```

How do I get the document names to only show MR 100 and disregard everything after the second space using jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can format the name using `split()` `slice()` and `join()`:

```
var s = "MR 100 12.12.10".split(" ").slice(0,2).join(" ");
```

How you can select each document title depends on how you have your page setup.